# Exporting list of arrays in python as csv

Tags: python, csv

I have a list of array in python that I'd like to export to a csv file, I am able to export a csv but am having some trouble with the line breaks. My list looks like this:

```
myList = [[itema, itemb], [itema_1,itemb_1], ... , [itema_n, itemb_n]]
```

I would like for my csv file to be like this:

```
itema, item
itema_1, item_1
...
itema_n, item_n
```

this is my current code, which gives me ([itema, itemb],[itema_1,itemb_1], etc.)

```
with open('sng_pyout', 'wb') as output:
    new_writer = csv.writer(output)
    new_writer.writerow(myList)
```

Comment: What is `newobject`? But anyway, you are using `writerow` once, no wonder you only have one row in the output file. Use `writerows` to write many rows at once.

Comment: sorry, that should have said myList

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're just telling the `csv.writer` to write a single row, since each call to `csv.writerow` will write one row with everything you pass into it. 
Instead:

```
with open('sng_pyout', 'wb') as output:
    new_writer = csv.writer(output)
    for sub_list in myList:
        new_writer.writerow(sub_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `writerows` (plural!) method to write all your rows at once:

```
with open('sng_pyout', 'wb') as output:
    new_writer = csv.writer(output)
    new_writer.writerows(myList)
```

The `writerow` (singular) takes a list of columns. And since your `myList` is a list, it assumed it's a list of columns, so it quoted its elements and wrote as csv:

```
"['jack', ' 4']","['mike', ' 12']"
```

The `writerows` (plural!) method expects a list of list of columns, and that's perfect for your `myList`.

Answer (score 0):

Try it as follows:

```
with open('sng_pyout', 'wb') as output:
    new_writer = csv.writer(output)
    for row in myList:
        new_writer.writerow(row)
```